# Reputation Gain from accepted answers (by me) does not show on rep graph

Tags: bug, status-completed, reputation-graph

Reputation gain (2 point) from accepted answers (accepted by me to others) does not show on rep graph.

Is it intentional or Am I missing something?

Edit: I have accepted 7 answers on my meta questions - 38929, 39664, 40623, 43006, 43790, 44108, 44974. None of them shown on [my rep graph](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/139541?tab=reputationhistory#tab-top).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually, [it erroneously assigns those two rep points to the reputation graph of the person whose answer was accepted](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/39509/anomalous-last-digit-tally-for-daily-rep/39745#39745).

Comment: I see, I can only regenerete "Accepting an answer: +0" at the moment though.

Comment: btw, I just checked on my answers that I got accepted, there is no +2 things like +17, looks like that issue was fixed.

Comment: @S.Mark: when you say you don't see the +17, do you mean in the list of questions to the right of the rep graph? That never showed the +17. But if you view source and look at the data used to generate the graph, and you happen to know a day when the only activity was that one of your answers was accepted, you'll see that the reputation is 17 points higher than it was the day before.

Comment: I have always found it odd that the reputation graph (and the recent activity list under the envelope) use different scoring algorithms than the One True Way in the reputation report. Wouldn't it be easier to call the same code?

Comment: I've checked based on JSON data, that rep-graph supposed to use. You could take a look that json file [here](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/rep-graph/139541/1265453682974.6/1270800000000.0?_=1270884853174).